# Is it possible to sum on webform

Tags: webforms

I'm newbie and made web form to fill with some values.
I want to sum all values on Column to make it has a total of column Value, like in excel to do sum of several values into one grand total.

Anyone experienced this ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tab titled "Analysis" for this. Alternatively you can use the "Download" option. See the example in the screenshot below.

[image: Analysis tab shows the sum]

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Webform Calculator](https://drupal.org/project/webform_calculator)

> Provides a formula webform component for computed values, where you
>   can enter a mathematical calculation based on the other fields. E.g.,
>   create a formula field with value formkey1 * 0.1 * formkey2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Webform Calculation Components](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculation_components).

> This module provides AJAX functionality to perform basic arithmetic operations on webform components.
>
> With this module the user can have calculated fields, e.g. the total amount, calculated percentage etc.

It works with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) 7.x-4.x

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sum the webform submission data, you can use Views Aggregator Plus 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator

You can put sum function in the columns you want to sum. You can put the results in end of the row.

Comment: I am not sure on how Views Aggregator works with forms.